# my procedure is executing twice, what is the problem?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have buffet table and I want to replace an ingredient with another, but my cursor replacing twice, and I get wrong answer.
Note: I'm using MySQL Workbench v 8.0.30

```
CREATE PROCEDURE cur_snak(in name_snak varchar(20), in old_ingred text,
in new_ingred text)
BEGIN
declare res text;
declare d int default 0;
declare c_id int ;
declare get_cur_ingred cursor for select id from buffet where `name`=name_snak;
declare continue handler  for sqlstate '02000'
set d=1;
declare continue handler  for sqlstate '23000'
set d=1;
open get_cur_ingred ;
lbl: loop
if d=1 then 
leave lbl;
end if;
if not d=1 then 
fetch get_cur_ingred into c_id ;
select insert((select ingredients from buffet where id=c_id ),
(select locate(old_ingred,ingredients) from buffet where id=c_id ),
(select length(old_ingred)),new_ingred) into res;
update buffet
set ingredients =res
where id=c_id;
end if;
end loop.
close get_cur_ingred;
END
```

Comment: Perhaps I've missed something, but cant you do this with a straightforward `UPDATE` query? Why do you need a procedure?

Comment: Move the fetch to before the exit test..